# Javascript - Firebase Auto Logout

Tags: javascript, firebase

I'm using firebase on my project and email authentication. I want to be automatically logged out 1 hours after the user logs in. If this not possible, I want to automatically logout when the user closes the website. Can anyone help me? Thanks a lot.

Comment: read the firebase docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For second point, set `firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.SESSION` or `NONE`.

Read more in: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence#modifying_the_auth_state_persistence